# extending a python class by adding more methods post definition

Tags: class, methods, python-3.x

```
class A:
    pass

def b(self):
    print('b')

A.b = b

a = A()
```

At this point a.b is a bound method object which is great, but if i say:

```
a.b()
```

I get an error saying that b needs at least one argument.

My questions are:
1. how does one go about tacking methods onto existing classes? and
2. are there any documented 'best practices' with regard to this sort of thing?

Comment: That exact code works for me.  Can you show the details of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work fine (see: http://ideone.com/WWPg8)

Python functions are descriptors, and convert to unbound and bound methods when accessed on classes and instances respectively; see http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html

"Monkey patching" classes and instances is considered perfectly OK, as long as you're clear about what you're doing and document it sufficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I made a typo in my code somewhere when I was testing that functionality